# Attach files to Mailgun via Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, email, mailgun

I'm trying to send attachments via mailgun, with my laravel project

the emails are working. I receive emails, but this is the first time we need to attach some files to add other function to our product

It seems that I am doing something wrong, because I can't get this working. I'm receiving an email with one attached file named "something.bin"

But I'm not attaching any bin. They are PDF, images (png, jpg, ...) files

```php
class SendTicket extends Mailable {
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    function __construct($from, $to, $subject, $attachments) {
        if (str_contains($to, 'email.com')) {
            return;
        }

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/'.config('app.mailgun_domain').'/messages');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        // This is the path to the file
        // I want to attach all the files in the future and send them
        $path = public_path() . '../storage/app/' . $attachments[0];

        $post = array(
            'from' => $from,
            'to' => $to,
            'subject' => $subject,
            'text'  =>'teste',
            'attachment' => $path,
        );
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api' . ':' . config('app.mailgun_secret'));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }

        curl_close($ch);
    }
}
```

Any idea that could help me attach the files? The $attachments variable has the full path of all files in the folder

SERVICES.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Third Party Services
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This file is for storing the credentials for third party services such
    | as Mailgun, Postmark, AWS and more. This file provides the de facto
    | location for this type of information, allowing packages to have
    | a conventional file to locate the various service credentials.
    |
    */

    'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
        'endpoint' => env('MAILGUN_ENDPOINT', 'api.eu.mailgun.net'),
    ],

    'postmark' => [
        'token' => env('POSTMARK_TOKEN'),
    ],

    'ses' => [
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
    ],

];
```

APP.php

```
    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),
    'mailgun_secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET', 'secret'),
    'mailgun_domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN', 'domain'),
```

ENV

```
MAIL_MAILER=mailgun
MAILGUN_ENDPOINT=api.eu.mailgun.net
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=aaa.aaa.pt  
MAILGUN_SECRET=7----------------------------------------8c351df0
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=info@dream.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Comment: Well, this would be easier for you if you use what Laravel offers... Depending on what version you have, you have a dedicated section on the Laravel docs that will show you how to use `Mail` instead of literally you sending/using `curl`... Read this: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/mail. And this tip: please, do not use `array(xxx)` as that is not used anymore (on modern code, standards), it will not break anything or be less performant, just flavors of the PHP community. And one last tip, if you have the Laravel 7.x+, you can use the `Http` facade: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client

Comment: @matiaslauriti thanks for the suggestion. But we want and need to use mailgun. We have templates created that we need to use

Comment: You can perfectly use `mailgun`, read the page I have shared about `mail`, you just need to use the correct driver/connection (`mailgun`) and that's it, the code will end up being way more readable for everyone; you could even test your mails (how they look like)

Comment: Request to Mailgun API failed, using the link you provided. I followed the instructions. DOMAIN, KEY and ENDPOINT are correctly set. Any idea?

Comment: I am not sure if you have to whitelist your IP or anything similar. I have never used Mailgun

Answer (score 1):

Since Mahdi let an answer, it helped me a lot.
Thanks to all answers, and I am reading about Laravels Mail in order to start using that function instead of curl.

Just needed to change a little things. The code working to send email with curl and mailgun:

```
class SendTicket  extends Mailable{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    function __construct($from, $to, $subject, $problem, $attachments){
        if(str_contains($to, 'email.com')){
            return;
        }

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/'.config('app.mailgun_domain').'/messages');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: multipart/form-data'));

        $post = array(
            'from' => $from,
            'to' => $to,
            'subject' => $subject,
            'text'  => $problem
        );

        // Attach all my files
        // Note that this files are with the full path, since the public_path to the file
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
            $post['attachment[' . $i . ']'] = curl_file_create($attachment);
            $i++;
        }  
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api' . ':' . config('app.mailgun_secret'));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}
```